# Can a player collect nobles after a day ends in Guillotine?

Tags: guillotine

I was playing the game with two friends and there were just two cards left on the second day, when my friend decided to use the **[Escape!]** card which allowed him to Randomize and discard 2 cards.

After this the day ended, we drew the next 12 cards. Then, my friend collected the first noble in line, saying that his last play (from day 2) was not over because he didn´t collect a noble, which is obligatory according to the rules.

Is this allowed?

Answer (score 3):

The day doesn't end when the line becomes empty.  It ends at the beginning of someone's turn if the line is empty.

After your friend plays Escape!, the line is randomized and two nobles discarded, resulting in an empty line.  Your friend tries and fails to collect the first noble in line (there no longer is one).  Then the day ends, a new day begins, and twelve new nobles are added to the line.

Your friend is out of luck, I'm afraid!  No noble for him until at least his next turn.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend doesn't collect a Noble, because that is the second step after playing an action card and **Escape** caused those nobles to be discarded. (Note: Your friend should draw an action card, since the next day doesn't begin until the start of the next players turn.)

The order of play is:

- Play an action card (optional)
- Collect the first noble in line
- Draw an action card (whether or not you played one)

From the [rules](http://www.headlesshollow.com/downloads/games/Guillotine_v1.pdf)

> Play continues until there are **no nobles** left in line **at the start of someone’s turn**. That day is then over and a new day begins: deal out 12 new noble cards from the noble deck.